# Ubuntu 16.04: Can't update packages because of IPv6 address

Tags: networking, dhcp, ipv6

I have a fresh installation of Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS (Xenial Xerus).

I added this to `/etc/network/interfaces` to assign an IPv4 address:

```
auto enp2s0
iface enp2s0 inet static
 address 192.168.1.100
 netmask 255.255.255.0
 gateway 192.168.1.1
```

However, the interface gets an IPv6, too. I don't know where it is coming from. There shouldn't be any IPv6 in this network, but I can't deny the possibility that some device is trying to assingn IP addresses, which is why I did not enable DHCP.

Now this seems to trigger AAAA instead of A lookups which prevents me from doing an `apt-get update`:

```
Cannot initiate the connection to th.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:3c8:9009:81::101:34). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:3c8:9009:81::101:34 80]
```

What to do?

Comment: @Ravexina Ok, yes, that would probably solve my apt-get problem but I guess other software will have the same problem, so I am looking for a solution that solves the root of the problem.

Comment: Could you please open a [new question](/questions/ask) if you have a new or follow-up question? The comment section is not suitable or meant for new questions or extended discussion. You’re welcome to send me a comment with a notification to draw my attention to it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

Since you're running Ubuntu Server, then please see [Disabling IPv6 on a single interface](https://askubuntu.com/questions/316492/disabling-ipv6-on-a-single-interface). And, you'll also want to add dns-nameservers to your interfaces file.

---

If you're running standard Ubuntu, then delete your changes to `/etc/network/interfaces` and setup a standard network connection profile to use DHCP to set your address (or manually set an address if you must) and DNS servers (comma-separated list), in the IPv4 tab, and set your IPv6 tab to `Ignore`...

[image]
[image]

You can also try another server instead of th.archive.ubuntu.com.

Comment: How do I do that using the command line? I don't have X.

Comment: Aren't you running standard Ubuntu? To disable IPv6 you can see https://askubuntu.com/questions/316492/disabling-ipv6-on-a-single-interface (and you'll also want to add dns-nameservers to your interfaces file).

Comment: Ubuntu Server, I edited that into the question.